# Функция для склонения существительных после числительных iOS (Obj-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c

Ищу функцию для склонения существительных после числительных iOS (Obj-c).

Comment: вас действительно интересует именно склонение числительных - "семи тысячам четыремстам семидесяти восьми"? Или таки существительных в зависимости от числа?

Comment: зачем этот вопрос здесь? для поиска есть гугл, а здесь нужно спрашивать если вы нашли функцию, но вам что-то непонятно, или что-то не работает в коде ... имхо

Comment: @Fabio, прежде чем разбрасываться подобными смелыми заявлениями, рекомендую вам еще раз пройти [Тур по Stack Overflow](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) и внимательно усвоить информацию о том, что тут можно спрашивать (информация в первом же абзаце). Несмотря на то, что вопрос действительно сформулирован крайне отвратительно и, сказал бы, невежливо, но он имеет право на существование на сайте.

Answer (score 7):

нашел на PHP (http://webhamster.ru/mytetrashare/index/mtb0/1886) и перевел Obj-c

```
//number - число перед словом
//arrayWords - массив склоняемого слова, например [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Бал", @"Балла", @"Баллов", nil];
-(NSString*)getWorkByDeclension:(int)number :(NSArray*)arrayWords{
    NSString* resultString = @"";
    number = number % 100;
    if (number >=11 && number <=19) {
        resultString = [arrayWords objectAtIndex:2];
    }else{
        int i = number % 10;
        switch (i) {
            case 1: resultString = [arrayWords objectAtIndex:0];
                break;
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4: resultString = [arrayWords objectAtIndex:1];
                break;
            default:
                resultString = [arrayWords objectAtIndex:2];
                break;
        }
    }
    return resultString;
}
```

Пример вызова функции

```
   NSArray* words = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Бал", @"Балла", @"Баллов", nil];

    NSString* testedWord = @"";
    for (int i=1; i<=100; i++) {
        testedWord = [self getWorkByDeclension:i :words];
        NSLog(@"number=%d %@",i,testedWord);
    }
```

Comment: Разве склонение числительных это не "пять, пяти, пятью..."?

Comment: Вы правы, нужно название исправить на "склонения существительных после числительных"

Comment: Спасибо *Fabio*, учту на будущее